# Adding a Rank to data in a Dictionary Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have data stored in a dictionary where `RunnerDetail` is a class of all the items within it.

```
Public runnerDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, RunnerDetail)
```

The key is an ID relating to each specific runner in the Dictionary called runnerId. There is also an Event ID in the dictionary values for the event where there are multiple runners within each event.

I then calculate the probability of each runner winning the event and add that back to the dictionary.

I then need some way of identifying which runner has the highest probability within each event

I've done this as follows but it feels very long winded and I am wondering if there is a more efficient way.

First I create a new table and add the `runnerId`, `eventId` and `probability`

```
   Dim rankTable As New DataTable()

        rankTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("runnerId"))
        rankTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("eventId"))
        rankTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("probability"))

        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, RunnerDetail) In runnerDictionary

            If Not kvp.Value.status = "REMOVED" Then
                Dim R1 As DataRow = rankTable.NewRow
                R1("eventId") = kvp.Value.eventId
                R1("runnerId") = kvp.Key
                R1("probability") = kvp.Value.probability
                rankTable.Rows.Add(R1)
            End If
        Next
```

Then sort the table by eventId and probability

```
rankTable.DefaultView.Sort = "eventId, probability ASC"
```

Then add a new column with the rank and then add this back to the dictionary.

```
rankTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("probabilityRank"))

Dim id As String = rankTable.Rows(0)(0).ToString
Dim startRank As Integer = 1
For i As Integer = 0 To rankTable.Rows.Count - 1

    If i = 0 Then
        rankTable.Rows(i)(3) = startRank
    Else
        If rankTable.Rows(i)(0) = id Then
            startRank += 1
            rankTable.Rows(i)(3) = startRank
            runnerDictionary(rankTable(i)(1)).probabilityRank = startRank
        Else
            startRank = 1
            rankTable.Rows(i)(3) = startRank
            runnerDictionary(rankTable(i)(1)).probabilityRank = startRank
            id = rankTable.Rows(i)(0).ToString
        End If

    End If

Next
```

The output would look something like this:

```
eventId    runnerId    probability    rank
a          1           0.54           1
a          2           0.24           2
a          3           0.22           3
b          4           0.60           1
b          5           0.30           2
b          6           0.10           3
```

Comment: Take a look at solving this problem with [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq).

Comment: I have looked already, hence my question....

Comment: "The index is an ID " Do you mean the Key instead of index? I know that seems nit-picky but if we are precise in our coding vocabulary it easier to get to a solution.

Comment: Why did you choose a Dictionary instead of a List(Of T)? Doesn't your RunnerDetail class include the ID property? It just complicates the coding a bit distinguishing the key and value elements.

Comment: @Mary I have only been coding in VB for 2 weeks so I am not familiar with things like Lists yet and yes, the ID in the key, also no, my RunnerDetail class does not include the ID, it has an ID for the market but not for the runner.

Comment: Both List an Dictionary are available in the .Net framework to any language using the framework. Since your class does not contain an ID property, I can see why you chose a Dictionary.

Comment: @Mary . . . Even if the `RunnerDetail` would have a property for that key value, there might be good reasons to use a dictionary instead of a list to hold the collection of `RunnerDetail` objects. The best reason would be if the collection would be searched intensively by that key value. That's possible in a list as well, of course, but it is a lot slower. If the key would be included as a property in the object itself, it might also be an option to create an own collection class that derives from `KeyedCollection(Of TKey, TItem)` and override its `GetKeyForItem` method.

Comment: @BartHofland yes I used a Dictionary because I read it was optimised for searching which I do a lot specifically by the key.

Comment: @BartHofland, you are correct but unless this is the Boston marathon, I don't think the optimization would be perceptible. When I have a minute I will do a timed test.

Comment: @Mary . . . You are correct as well. It depends on the situation. I tried it shortly with a two small collections of 20 elements. One list and one dictionary. I created an array with 1,000,000 random key values for the test beforehand. In the first loop, I fetched the corresponding elements from the list using the `Find` method. In the second loop, I fetched the corresponding elements from the dictionary using the key. Results: ca. 230ms for list, ca. 20ms for dictionary. After increasing the number of collection elements to 100, the results were: ca. 800ms for list, ca. 20ms for dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the example from Bart below and come up with this.

Ordering the data in the Dictionary and then adding a sequencial number within each eventId seems to do the trick.
Does anyone see any potential problems with this?

```
    Dim currentMarketId As String = "x"
    Dim rank As Integer = 1

    For Each rd In runnerDictionary.Values.Where(Function(x) x.status <> "REMOVED").OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.eventId).ThenByDescending(Function(x) x.probability)
        If rd.eventId = currentMarketId Then
            rank += 1
        Else
            rank = 1
            currentMarketId = rd.eventId
        End If
        rd.probabilityRank = rank

    Next
```

Comment: This is possible too, of course. This resembles your own programming logic more closely. This way you do not need the `rankDictionary`. Instead you add another level of sorting. I am not sure which solution is faster or more flexible, but this should do the job just as well. :)

Comment: However, you seem to have switched back from `eventId` to `marketId`...

Comment: And instead of `initialId`, I would have chosen the name `currentMarketId` or `currentEventId`. That would express its purpose more clearly imo.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could create a dictionary that holds the increasing ranks per `eventId` while you loop through the dictionary of runner details?

```
Dim rankDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

For Each rd In runnerDictionary.Values.Where(Function(x) x.status <> "REMOVED").OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.probability)
    Dim rank As Integer

    If rankDictionary.ContainsKey(rd.eventId) Then
        rank = rankDictionary(rd.eventId) + 1
        rankDictionary(rd.eventId) = rank
    Else
        rank = 1
        rankDictionary.Add(rd.eventId, rank)
    End If

    rd.probabilityRank = rank
Next
```

Advantages:

- Just a single loop
- No slow datatable
- <s>No need for sorting</s> Only need for sorting on one level (probability)

I haven't tested it, since you did not provide any testing data (input and output data). Also, I had to derive the `RunnerDetail` class/structure from the code you provided because you omitted it. Please provide such details in future questions, since it may considerably ease answering them.

**Edit**

Initially, I thought sorting was unnecessary, but afterwards I realized that the order of the ranking should be the same as the order of the probability values per market id. I fixed my answer accordingly.

**Edit 2**

Based on new insights regarding the data structure, I have updated my answer to use `eventId` instead of `marketId` for determining the ranking of the runners. I assumed that `eventId` is of type `String` as well. I that's not the case, you should change the key type of `rankDictionary` accordingly.

**Edit 3**

I overlooked the status of the runner details. Removed items should be neglected. Fixed my code accordingly.

**Edit 4**

Assuming that the highest probability should be assigned to the rank with the lowest numerical value (rank 1), the runner details should be sorted in descending order of probability. Fixed my code accordingly.

Comment: I am confused as to how this ranks the values? Won't this just add a sequence within each market? I have only been coding a few weeks so I could be missing something?

Comment: Yes, it would. When I went to bed last night, I thought about the sorting. You did not only sort on marketId (to detect changes in marketId) but also on probability. So a sorting might be necessary. I will fix that in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating - The sorting needs to be within each event, so Usain Bolt is in race 1, his probability is 54%, his rank is 1 within his event. Asafa Powell is in race 2 and he also has a 54% probability and his rank is also 1 within his event and so on. I should end up with a rank for every runner relative to runners within their own event and mapped to their runner_id so I can reference it later.

Comment: I see. After re-reading it, you might have multiple runners with the same event ID. But in your own code, you are currently not sorting/grouping by that event ID, right? Is the event ID property in your `RunnerDetail` class perhaps called `eventId`? In your code, you are sorting by `marketId`. I assume that is something entirely else? When you say "I then need some way of identifying which runner has the highest probability within each event", do you even need to do something with that market id? Do you either need to group by a combination of event ID and market ID, or only by event ID?

Comment: You also speak of a `runner_id` property... I cannot find any details about that property either. Is it the same as the `selectionId` field corresponding to the dictionary key value? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Apologies I have edited my question. runnerId is the key within the RunnerDictionary and is unique to each runner. Within each event there will be multiple runners who's probability is relative to that event only. So there will be 5 events today, each event has 8 runners. Each runner has a probability relative to their event, so within each event the rank would be 1 to 8, where 1 is the highest probability of winning that event.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I used your example and posted a solution, this seems to work unless you can see any issues with it.